# How to speed up Function in powershell

Tags: powershell, function

I am getting object ids from function. where $objects has 1000 entries. Below is part of main script. Just to get object ids for 1000 OBJECTS running for hours. If $objects count under 10 it runs quick. Is there way I can speed up below function to process 1000 $objects ???

```
function get_nodes($obj){

        if($obj.protectionSource.name -eq $objectName){
            $global:_object_id = $obj.protectionSource.id
            $global:object = $obj.protectionSource.name
            #break
        }
        if($obj.name -eq $objectName){
            $global:_object_id = $obj.id
            $global:object = $obj.name
           # break
        }        
        if($obj.PSObject.Properties['nodes']){
            foreach($node in $obj.nodes){
                if($null -eq $global:_object_id){
                    get_nodes $node
                }
            }
        }
        if($obj.PSObject.Properties['applicationNodes']){
            foreach($node in $obj.applicationNodes){
                if($null -eq $global:_object_id){
                    get_nodes $node
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    foreach($source in $sources){
        if($null -eq $global:_object_id){
            get_nodes $source
        }
    }
    return $global:_object_id
}



foreach($object in $objects){   ###2
# get object ID
$objectId = getObjectId $object
                            }
```

$sources may have 1000 or more entries. below is one entry. $objects are literally server names ( server1 , server2 etc).

```
 PS C:\anil\scripts> $sources[0]|ConvertTo-Json
{
    "nodes":  [
                  {
                      "nodes":  "                    ",
                      "protectionSource":  "@{id=2; parentId=1; name=Datacenters; environment=kVMware; vmWareProtectionSource=}",
                      "protectedSourcesSummary":  "",
                      "unprotectedSourcesSummary":  "",
                      "logicalSize":  0
                  }
              ],
    "protectionSource":  {
                             "id":  1,
                             "name":  "wpc1uv00vvc.ent.ad.ntrs.com",
                             "environment":  "kVMware",
                             "vmWareProtectionSource":  {
                                                            "type":  "kVCenter",
                                                            "name":  "wpc1uv00vvc.ent.ad.ntrs.com",
                                                            "id":  "@{uuid=683FECB1-A27E-447A-8037-0E1B8DA4BE7A}",
                                                            "version":  "VMware vCenter Server 6.0.0 build-7462484",
                                                            "isVmcEntity":  false
                                                        }
                         },
    "protectedSourcesSummary":  [
                                    {
                                        "environment":  "kVMware"
                                    }
                                ],
    "unprotectedSourcesSummary":  [
                                      {
                                          "environment":  "kVMware",
                                          "leavesCount":  24,
                                          "totalLogicalSize":  1224065679360
                                      }
                                  ],
    "registrationInfo":  {
                             "accessInfo":  {
                                                "id":  3953,
                                                "version":  0,
                                                "environment":  "kVMware",
                                                "endpoint":  "wpc1uv00vvc"
                                            },
                             "throttlingPolicy":  {
                                                      "isEnabled":  false,
                                                      "enforceMaxStreams":  false
                                                  },
                             "registrationTimeUsecs":  1585846901734416,
                             "refreshTimeUsecs":  1670355941177325,
                             "refreshErrorMessage":  "Failed to connect to wpc1uv00vvc. Error: SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client[no subcode] \"System error\" Detail: getadd
rinfo failed in tcp_connect(). Connectivity status: Connection to wpc1uv00vvc:443 resulted in : Failed to resolve server name with error: System error",
                             "authenticationStatus":  "kFinished",
                             "username":  "ent\\sys-poc-cohesity"
                         }
}

PS C:\anil\scripts>
```

Comment: what is `$objectName` inside your function? It's never passed as an argument. You can definitely speed up this by using a `Stack<T>` or `Queue<T>` but there is not enough context to help you up. Btw, doing `$obj.PSObject.Properties['nodes']` and `$obj.PSObject.Properties['applicationNodes']` is not really needed. You can just let `foreach` enumerate it if it exists

Comment: maybe give us some examples of these `$objects` as Json and what you expect as a result from your function, we should be able to understand and help you better

Comment: Could you `$sources[0] | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99` and paste it here cleaning up the data that we should not see?

Comment: Not enough context to help you.   Give me a simple input and expected output.

Comment: Where is `getObjectId` defined?